# Calling createCaptureSession in a background thread

Tags: android, android-camera2

When calling [createCaptureSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(android.hardware.camera2.params.SessionConfiguration)) this one takes around 200ms to comeback in my test device.
I thought this call was asynchronous, so it is very strange that it takes so long.

To mitigate the issue I am now calling it from a background thread in order to not block the UI while these 200ms. And for the call I am re-using the same thread (executor) that I am passing in the [SessionConfiguration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/SessionConfiguration).

So far I've found no side effects. But I would like to know if it is fine to perform such call on a background thread, or I may encounter problems in specific use-cases, device models, android versions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that can be experienced there may be a problem due to the fact that the android device is single-core or a process that requires performance at that time. However, this is a problem caused by the device and user, not by the developer.

1. We know that there are no single core Android phones.
2. Threads do not cause any problems since they are software elements that come into play during this performance load. Only in case of load the processing is done a little later